# Function is giving an error before it's being called

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This question is about Google Apps Script which is JavaScript based so have aded the JavaScript tag in the hope of tapping into a larger group of followers. Not sure if my issues is specific to the environment or not.

Here is a small script:

```
function onEdit() {

  // create the campaign portfolio lookup function
  function channelLookup(month_num) {
    var lookup_formula = '=ARRAYFORMULA(if($A$16:$A="",,iferror(VLOOKUP($C$16:$C,lookups!$E$3:$F$100,2,false),"not recognized in lookup")))';
    var the_cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('starts ' + month_num + ' month' ).getRange('E16');
    var cell_content = the_cell.getValues();
    if(cell_content == "") {
      the_cell.setFormula(lookup_formula);
    } else {
      Logger.log('the_cell is not empty');
    }
  }

  // loop through the 13 reports
  for ( var i=0; i<14; i++ ) {
    channelLookup(i);
  }
}
```

I don't actually call the function till the for loop further down. But, when I try to save and/or run the script I receive an error message:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 6, file
>   "Code")

This concerns the line starting `var the_cell = SpreadsheetApp...`

Since I'm only building the function at this stage and not actually calling it, why am I receiving this error? Variable the_cell has not been defined yet since I have not called the function yet?

*Alternative structure following comments*

```
// create the campaign portfolio lookup function

function channelLookup(month_num) {
  var lookup_formula = '=ARRAYFORMULA(if($A$16:$A="",,iferror(VLOOKUP($C$16:$C,lookups!$E$3:$F$100,2,false),"not recognized in lookup")))';
  var the_cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('starts ' + month_num + ' month' ).getRange('E16');
  Logger.log(the_cell);
  var cell_content = the_cell.getValues();
  if(cell_content == "") {
    the_cell.setFormula(lookup_formula);
  } else {
    Logger.log('the_cell is not empty');
  }
}

function onEdit() {
  // loop through the 13 reports
  for ( var i=0; i<14; i++ ) {
    channelLookup(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `onEdit` is not being called anywhere?

Comment: @MinusFour within the context of my environment onEdit() refers to any change to the google-spreadsheet that this function is linked to. However, within this env I can use a "run" button for testing. I doubt the onEdit trigger is the issue since I can remove that completely and test the function and arrive at the same result

Comment: In programming, things don't happen by themselves. Something, somewhere is calling `onEdit()`.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you. This is a runtime error, so something has to be calling it.

Comment: You realize the reason for the TypeError? It's because `getSheetByName` is returning null.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Please see code block above, I have taken channelLookup() outside of onEdit(). @MinusFour RE getSheetByName. That's correct. The logged value of e.g. month_num = 1 is "starts 1 month" which is the name of a sheet in this spreadsheet. So, once the desired sheet name has been concatenated together using 'starts ' + month_num + ' month' the method that follows getRange() should give a value

Comment: use `onEdit(e)` function and with `e.Range` you can find the cell which is editing, so you can realise what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string concatenation may not be doing what you think it is. The error is clearly saying that the result of `getSheetByName()` is `null`.

Just to convince yourself, instead of:

```
var the_cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('starts ' + month_num + ' month' ).getRange('E16');
```

Break it down:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetname = 'starts ' + month_num + ' month';
Logger.log( sheetname );
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
if (!sheet) {
  throw new Error( "No such sheet: "+sheetname );
}
var the_cell = sheet.getRange('E16');
```